# how can i fix this pyrmid of stars in java

Tags: java

I have to print pyrmids of stars by the user input,
the user input: how many rows,and how many columns.
i stared with 1 star and increment the stars every iteration by 2,
and decrement the rows by 1.
i cant to determine how many spaces i have to do.

***what i have to do : 
examples :***

```
printStars(4,2) rows = 4 , columns = 2.
output :

   *       *
  ***     ***
 *****   *****
******* *******

printStars(3,3) rows= 3 , columns =3.
output : 

  *     *     *
 ***   ***   ***
***** ***** *****

printStars(3,4) rows = 3 , columns =4.
output:
  *     *     *     *
 ***   ***   ***   ***
***** ***** ***** *****
```

***The code:***

```
private static void printStars(int rows, int columns ) {

        int stars = 1;

        while (rows > 0) {

            int spaces = rows;

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {


                for (int sp = spaces; sp >=1; sp--) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for (int st = stars; st >= 1; st--) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
            stars += 2;
            rows--;

        }

    }
```

***what i get :***

```
printStars(3,4)
output:
   *   *   *   *
  ***  ***  ***  ***
 ***** ***** ***** *****
```

Comment: Here's a suggestion: treat each pyramid as a rectangle instead of a pyramid. That is to say, each row in the pyramid is the same length as the longest (bottom) row. Then the difference between each row is the number and position of asterisks. If the longest row needs you to print 9 characters, then the top row also needs you to print 9 characters. The bottom row needs 9 asterisks, while the top needs 1 asterisk and 8 spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first sight it seems that you are not accounting for the spaces that come **after** you have printed the stars. Try to modify the code like this:

```
private static void printStars(int rows, int columns)
{

    int stars = 1;

    while (rows > 0) {

        int spaces = rows;

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {

            for (int sp = spaces; sp >= 1; sp--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int st = stars; st >= 1; st--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int sp = spaces; sp >= 1; sp--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        stars += 2;
        rows--;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Agar123 Welcome